# How Can I determine is digit Even number?

Tags: t-sql

Bit rusty on the old sql.

Can you help?

Given a number eg 1 or 2 or 4 I need to determine if it's even or odd number and do some calculation 
depending if even or odd .

How do you detect that in sql (sql server 2000)
thanks a lot

Comment: is there a `mod` function of some sort in tsql?

Comment: @jason: Tsql supports the modulo operator %

Answer (score 51):

Use the modulus operator `n % 2`. It returns 0 if the number is even, and 1 if the number is odd.

Comment: Do you do something like
Declare @myNumber int
set @myNumber=1
 if Select (@myNumber% 2)=1
      print 'even'
    else
      print 'odd'

Comment: Yes, or if you want to do it inside a select, use the "case ... when ... then" construct.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use sql server BIT WISE operators

```
DECLARE @Int INT

SELECT @Int = 103

SELECT @Int & 1, @Int % 2
```

Comment: for some reason i cannot get to work what i need to do calculate if a number is even or odd then divide by 10 and get the reminder only 
   DECLARE @myNumber INT ,@result int 
   SELECT @myNumber = 16 
   SELECT @myNumber & 1, @myNumber % 2 

   if @myNumber=0-- even 
    set @result=@myNumber x 1-- multiply by 1
   else set @result=@myNumber x 2-- multiply by 2 

    --- then divide by 10 and 
     --example
    if result =5.2 just take the reminder (in this case 2)

     select result

Comment: Try this

declare @myNumber int ,@result int
set @myNumber = 16 
select  
 Result = 
 (case when @myNumber % 2 = 0 then @myNumber * 1 else @myNumber * 2 end) %10

Comment: DECLARE @myNumber INT ,@result int 
SELECT @myNumber = 16 
SELECT @myNumber & 1, @myNumber % 2 
if @myNumber=0-- even 
set @result=@myNumber * 1-- multiply by 1 
else set @result=@myNumber * 2-- multiply by 2 
select @result % 10

Answer (score 6):

declare @t table(num int)
insert into @t select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4

```
select 
    num
    ,case when num % 2 = 0 then 'Even' else 'Odd' end as Status
from @t
```

Output:

**num   Status**

```
1   Odd
2   Even
3   Odd
4   Even
```

e.g. If the number is even(multiply by 1) or odd (multiply by 2) then divide by 10 and get the remainder

```
declare @myNumber int ,@result int
set @myNumber = 16 
select  
    Result = 
    (case when @myNumber % 2 = 0 then @myNumber * 1 else @myNumber * 2 end) %10
```

**Result**

```
6
```

when `@myNumber = 11` then

**Result**

```
2
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

I am using the same thing in MS SQL SP as follows:

```
IF @current_number % 2 = 0 SET @something = 1
```

-- or  --

```
IF @current_number % 2 = 0 exec sp_whatever
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [modulus operator (%)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276866(SQL.80).aspx).

```
x % 2
```

will tell you if x is even or odd.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say for a table STATION.

Schema:

ID NUMBER

CITY VARCHAR

STATE VARCHAR

```sql
-- You can use any of the mentioned criteria to fetch the even ID.

-- 1. MOD() Fucntion

select distinct CITY from STATION as st where MOD(st.id,  2) = 0

-- 2. % function

select distinct CITY from STATION as st where st.id % 2 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

NOT INTENDED AS A SERIOUS ANSWER...BUT IT WORKS.

Please reserve the following for giving to people you don't like who simply want a quick answer without wanting to understand the solution (i.e people wanting to cheat).

```
--Enter the whole integer you want to check
declare @number int = 115

--The check is independent of sign
set @number = abs(@number)
declare @OriginalNumber int = @number

--Firstly, we need to peform the Wilhelm Leibniz conversion, 64 length to allow for very big numbers
declare @WilhelmLeibnizConversion varchar(64) = ''

declare @currentBit int = power(8,exp(log(1))+1)

while @currentBit > 0
begin

    set @WilhelmLeibnizConversion=convert(char(1), @number % 2) + @WilhelmLeibnizConversion

    set @number = convert(int, (@number / 2)) 

    set @currentBit-=1

end

--Although checking the 1 bit value of the Wilhelm Leibniz conversion is usually enough, for robust code you should also include the Kimmo Eriksson Factors one and two.
declare @KimmoErikssonFactor1 int = (@OriginalNumber + 1) % 2
declare @KimmoErikssonFactor2 int = (@OriginalNumber - 1) & 1

--Now check all 3 for 100% confirmation on the parity of your original number.
select case when right(@WilhelmLeibnizConversion,1) = 0 and (@KimmoErikssonFactor1 + @KimmoErikssonFactor2 <> 0) then 'Even' else 'Odd' end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the 1-bit of the hex value of the number.  If that bit is on, then it is odd.

```
DECLARE @Int INT

SELECT CASE WHEN @Int&0x0001<>0 THEN 'ODD' ELSE 'EVEN' END
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator retrieves the modulus, so checking the modulus of a division by 2 you can know if it is odd or even.

```
DECLARE @i int =1;
while @i <= 20
begin 
    if @i % 2 = 0
    PRINT @i
    IF @i = 10 PRINT 'halfway there!';
    set @i = @i+1;
end
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information.

Answer (score -1):

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO

SELECT BusinessEntityID,
    CASE BusinessEntityID % 2
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Even' ELSE 'Odd' END AS "Status"
FROM HumanResources.Employee;
GO
```